# Batch testing a Python function containing input([promp])

Tags: python, input

Suppose I have a function containing input command as such:

```
def foo:
    input("Enter value:")
```

To run multiple times without needing user input, I am attempting to write a function such that it takes list of values for each run

```
def bar(values):
    .....
    .....
```

How do I run foo multiple times inside bar and use the list (values) for the input inside foo instead of user manual input?

Comment: *To run multiple times without needing user input,*  and *run foo multiple times inside bar* -- these two statements are contradictory. Consider editing your question to include more detail about how you intend this to work, with sample input and expected outputs, etc.

Comment: if you do not want user input then why you want to use `input()` ?

Comment: Function normally supposed to take user input and my actual function runs in a infinite while loop until exited. For testing, it is pain to enter values as a user input. So for testing purpose, I was checking if there is a way to read values from a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default argument that is equal to `None` when your function is run in interactive mode:

```
def foo(value=None):
    if value is None:
        value = input("Enter value:")
```